# Custom reference field line in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters

Following on from a previous question, I took the route of co-opting the location field to display some invoice related information in the top right corner of the letter. Now I'd like to do something similar with the reference fields line and use it for a purpose other than its own.

I have used `\removereffields` to empty the reference fields line, now it just displays a date. I can't see an easy way of using the reference fields line like it was possible with the location field `\setkomavar{location}{... stuff here ...}`. I have read the `scrlttr2.cls`, and it seems that the reference field is just 'magically' rendered if any of the reference fields are set.

Is it possible to use the reference fields line for my purposes and what is the easiest way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add variables to the reference line using `\addtoreffields{variable name}`. But you can't add free text to the reference line. Maybe you could use something like [asymTypB.lco](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-E/source/asymTypB.lco) to add a free defined line.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. What does asymTypB.lco actually do? It looks like it makes a column on the right hand side? I'm basically trying to get a line of info right where the reference fields line is. Looks like a good start anyway. Maybe I could redeclare `\@set@reffield`?

Comment: @NickSandford: asymTypB.lco uses a picture environment to \put elements, whereever they are wanted. You may use the same trick. Or try package textpos to place your elements. I don't think that redeclaration of internal macros like \@set@reffield is a good idea. This would be a very ugly hack and may break scrlttr2 or may be broken by changes of scrlttr2 in future.

Comment: Ah, ok. Makes more sense than what I ended up doing which was to use the to address field to add the stuff below. I'll have another look at asmTypB.lco and see if I can get that to work, would probably be better than how it is now :). I never ended up redeclaring \@set@reffield, thankfully.